# web3 ens library - purpose of setText, getText against ENS name

Tags: web3js, ens

I am looking at web3.eth.ens library, I can see methods setText and getText, which allows you to set and get key value pairs against an ENS name. What is the purpose of this? Also is there a way to find all the keys against an ENS name?

Answer (score 0):

The functions `setText()` and `text()` allow ENS name holders to associate metadata with a ENS name.

Both are functions of the [`TextResolver.sol`](https://github.com/ensdomains/resolvers/blob/master/contracts/profiles/TextResolver.sol) contract.

---

From ENS docs:

```
function setText(bytes32 node, string calldata key, string calldata value) external authorised(node)
```

> Sets text metadata for `node` with the unique key `key` to `value`,
>   overwriting anything previously stored for `node` and `key`. To clear
>   a text field, set it to the empty string.

```
function text(bytes32 node, string calldata key) external view returns (string memory)
```

> Retrieves text metadata for `node`. Each name may have multiple pieces
>   of metadata, identified by a unique string `key`. If no text data exists
>   for `node` with the key `key`, the empty string is returned.

[Standard values for key](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/publicresolver#get-text-data)